# Cross-domain font-face issues

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-domain, font-face

please read all of this before commenting.

I'm currently working on a large website which is hosted on Amazon Web Services (AWS). This allows us to use scalability features in situations where the website might take a big traffic load.

Originally we started by separating out the code of the website a mix of HTML/PHP/Java etc and have static assets on a separate server. When I first tried using font-face in this setup I found that Firefox and IE would not load the font, and quickly discovered it was a cross-domain issue. There are a variety of solutions to this, which include modifying headers to allow access to the font files. However, the storage system we're using doesn't allow for this type of header modification.

In a bid to see if I could just get the fonts to work across all browsers I moved them and the CSS file that calls them to the same domain as the website. However they still don't seem to load up in Firefox or IE. If I copy the code and run it locally in my documents everything seems fine in all browsers (so the files cannot be corrupt). Firefox is definitely finding the files as I can see them being loaded via FireBug.

I've checked all URLs to make sure they're correct and resolve where they should.

Here's the font-face CSS I'm using with the smiley hack:

```
@font-face {
    font-family : "AllerRegular";
    src : url('aller_rg-webfont.eot');
    src : local('☺'),
          url('aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
          url('aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
          url('aller_rg-webfont.svg#webfontooYDBZYS') format('svg');
    font-weight : normal;
    font-style : normal;
}
```

The CSS file sits in the same directory as the fonts.

I also have the MIME types set in a .htaccess file which sits in the same folder as the fonts.

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/truetype .ttf
AddType font/opentype .otf
AddType font/opentype .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
AddEncoding gzip .svgz
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

If you have any ideas please suggest.
 I've been searching the web for a few days now but all solutions have failed me.

Comment: Might be a long shot but, are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: Not when running the site in the local development environment. It's a local Tomcat and Apache install.

Comment: Random guess - in CSS, unlike JS, the relative URL's are relative to the path of included CSS file and NOT the document this file is included in. Is that causing this to happen?

Comment: I can confirm that the paths to the font files are relative from the CSS file and not the HTML/PHP document.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892691/font-face-fonts-only-work-on-their-own-domain

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, serving webfonts from AWS likely won't work in Firefox and IE 9+ because AWS doesn't support the Access-Control-Origin-Header. See this [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=34281&start=100&tstart=0) on the AWS forums. Seems to be a problem for a lot of people.

Update 7/17/12:

As an alternative to AWS, Google's cloud services support cross-origin file serving. I just set up a bucket to serve webfonts, and it seems to be working. See this blog [post](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/03/google-cloud-storage-adds-several.html) and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) for more info.

Comment: Ah, I hope they implement support for it soon.

Comment: AWS has added custom origin support in CloudFront.  So, you can create a CloudFront distribution with your server as custom origin and serve the font with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and CloudFront will include that header with cached responses.

Comment: AWS now supports custom origin support without Cloudfront using CORS, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24181448/168012

Comment: it seems that safari still does not send the cross origin headers for font face, so although the font still gets downlaoded and works fine, but S3 does not respond with cors headers unless the browser sends a cross origin request, which means that you might still face issues with preloading cross origin fonts in safari, as there would be a preload request with cors, and a css font face request without CORS, and safari might cache the css response and try to use it later for the preload response which would fail because of missing cors headers

Comment: @gaurav5430 I am facing the same issue with Safari only. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 8):

Try do this:

On your server you will need to add:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

To the header of the font files, so for example if you are using Apache you can add this to the .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

My problem solved with this method.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible using S3 without Cloudfront by adding the following CORS configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

http://html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/18/configure-amazon-s3-for-cross-origin-resourse-sharing-to-host-a-web-font/

http://blog.blenderbox.com/2012/10/12/serving-font-face-fonts-to-firefox-from-an-s3-bucket/

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You may well need to add support for the MIME types on the new hosting environment.

Take a look at:

http://www.jbarker.com/blog/2011/web-fonts-mime-types

Comment: Interesting... will have a look.

Comment: Hmmm... I appear to have setup the MIME types already... will add to original post. Let me know if they look correct or not.