# Adidng font-face to my site from external url is not working

Tags: html, font-face

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
                src: url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.eot');
                src: url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                         url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.woff') format('woff'),
                         url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
                         url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.svg#oswaldregularwebfont') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;

}
```

Note** : I am doing this on amazon webstore i have also tried this on local html file 
but this does the same thing... not working am i doing something wrong..

Thanks

Comment: Well, the URLs are reachable. Can you show us where you've applied this new font in your CSS rules?

Comment: :) I want to add that i have resolver the issue... After searching i found that we need to add a .htaccess file on the server for allowing another site font support..                                           # example Apache .htaccess file to add access control header
 
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>                                                                         more info at https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/beautiful-fonts-with-font-face/

Comment: I would suggest to add that as your own answer and then mark it as accepted, in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt 1:
Standard practice is to always use `http://` in the url. Fix that in your code and try again.

Attempt 2:
I think you are making a cross domain request to the font which is intentionally blocked by many servers as a measure of protection against someone just linking to the fonts, effectively stealing the server bandwidth and possibly violating the font's EULA.

So if you have access to the server where the fonts are stored, you can edit the configuration file to allow cross domain requests for fonts, if you have already measured the risks!

Attempt 3:
Some people have reported that serving webfonts from AWS likely won't work in Firefox and IE 9+ because AWS doesn't support the Access-Control-Origin-Header. Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245464/cross-domain-font-face-issues)!

So you will have to host the fonts on servers that support cross domain access for webfonts.

Comment: Except that the font-face rule works as-is - hence the jsFiddle in my answer. Regardless, the OP has already stated (in the comments) that he fixed this.

Comment: Yeah..the solution to his problem was also suggested by me in 'Attempt 2' to edit the configuration file to allow cross domain requests for webfonts.

Answer (score 1):

This font-face works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/xBmTG/

```
@font-face {   
    font-family: 'Oswald';                 
    src:    url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.eot');                 
    src:    url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
            url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.woff') format('woff'), 
            url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
            url('http://www.dev.icyberking.com/fonts/oswaldregularwebfont.svg#oswaldregularwebfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;  
}


body
{
    font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
}
```

I assume the problem lies in your selectors in the rest of your CSS file.