# Why `@font-face` url cannot cross domain by default?

Tags: css, url, font-face

As with `@import url(...)`, a remote domain can be provided in the `url` specified when importing a font with `@font-face: { src: url(...) }`.

For example:

```
/*声明 WebFont*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'source';
  src: url('https://some/remote/domain/font/source.eot');
    ...
}
```

Specifying a remote domain results in a browser error by default. What is the reason for this restriction?

Comment: I reworded and clarified the question.

Comment: Though not a duplicate, [Cross-domain font-face issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8245464/2985643) may be relevant.

Comment: @skomisa thank u saving my poor English. I wanna know why browser have that strategy.

Comment: The reason that browsers don't allow this is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). See this [_"Cross Domain Fonts"_](https://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-fonts) article for a brief explanation, and how to resolve it.  Firefox links to this [_"What Went Wrong"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default) article in a Console error message when you try to load your load your page with `@font-face` specifying a remote domain. Does that clarify the situation?

Comment: @skomisa clear！ understand ！