# CSS3 @font-face in Firefox changes according to URL prefix

Tags: css, url, firefox, fonts

While using Firefox (v16), I've noticed that depending on the URL prefix, a CSS font will or will not load...

By prefix I mean the three letters 'www.'

Here is an example:

http://www.purplemartinpress.com/

Vs...

http://purplemartinpress.com/

When using the 'www' prefix in Firefox, the font doesn't load. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox (and really most any other browser) treats the www subdomain like any other subdomain — that is, a URL with the www subdomain is not the same as one without, even if their second-level and top-level domains are the same, and so are mismatching. If you have mismatching domains, then your `@font-face` fonts won't load in Firefox. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892691/font-face-fonts-only-work-on-their-own-domain/2892697#2892697) for details.

The easy way out of this is to either use domain-relative URLs when linking to resources under the same domain (removing the `http://purplemartinpress.com` portion of your URLs) or to canonicalize your URL to either always have the www, or never.