# @font-face NOT working when accessing "www.domain.tld" but WORKING with "domain.tld"

Tags: html, css, django, apache

### Problem

If i access my site via `www.domain.tld` the `@font-face` rule is omited.
If i go to `domain.tld` (without the 'www' part) `@font-face` is regarded.
All other css formattings are working in both cases fine.

### CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url(../fonts/font-name.eot);
    src: local("font-name"), url(../fonts/font-name.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

### Django

In my Django `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/domain.tld/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://domain.tld/static/'
```

If i change it to `STATIC_URL = 'http://www.domain.tld/static/'` the `@font-face` rule is omited on `domain.tld` and regarded on `www.domain.tld` so it's the reverse behavior.

### Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.tld.log combined

    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/domain.tld/wsgi


    Alias /static/ /var/www/domain.tld/static/

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/domain.tld/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/domain.tld/static/img/favicon.ico
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why do you use a STATIC_URL with the FQDN? just use '/static/' and let Apache handle the rest.

Comment: Just try url in quotes `src: url('../fonts/font-name.eot');`

Comment: Yes because browsers consider even font loading from different domains a bad idea (cross site).

Comment: @petkostas Because i thought it's the same. Hm, i tested it and now it seems to work, but i can't figure out why (completely different domains should work too)...Furthermore all other css rules are in both cases regarded. Has somebody an explanation?

Comment: @Hareesh tried it out, but has no influence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cross-domain Web font embedding is denied by some browsers (not sure if it applies to all or some), and I believe this should remain as is (security wise).
Apart from that, you don't need a FQDN either for STATIC_URL or MEDIA_URL your web server takes care serving static content, the url is used for providing a identifiable url for asset loading. So if you visit your website from a subdomain not everything is going to work if you have a FQDN in your static, remove the FQDN and just use the directory name you want, makes it easier also to port settings to a sandbox or a production system with multiple subdomains.
You can also further check this stackoverflow question (there are some solutions provided, mind though that I don't know if its working as I never had such an issue):

[@font-face fonts only work on their own domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892691/font-face-fonts-only-work-on-their-own-domain)