# CSS Import Font Issue

Tags: css, fonts, import

I am trying to import a font from a web-kit. The code is in place and the fonts are uploaded to server but won't show on site.

**CSS**

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'gauntlet_thinregular';
        src: url('http://dharmafund.net/fonts/gauntletthin_tb-webfont.eot');
        src: url('http://dharmafund.net/fonts/gauntletthin_tb-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('http://dharmafund.net/fonts/gauntletthin_tb-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('http://dharmafund.net/fonts/gauntletthin_tb-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('http://dharmafund.net/fonts/gauntletthin_tb-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('http://dharmafund.net/fonts/gauntletthin_tb-webfont.svg#gauntlet_thinregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
       font-family: 'gauntlet_thinregular'!important; 
    }
```

I tried this code on a Wordpress install and it worked but it's not working on this other platform I'm using (CrowdfundHQ). Any thoughts?

Website URL: http://dharma-fund.crowdfundhq.com

Thanks

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892691/font-face-fonts-only-work-on-their-own-domain - (this includes sub-domain)

Comment: Richard, thank you. Adding the following code to .htaccess worked

Answer (score 3):

The fonts are now loading afer adding the following code to .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```