# sourcing fonts in css

Tags: html, css, fonts

So I'm having trouble getting fonts to source properly. 
I have in my `public_html`, `index.php` which uses the stylesheet stored in a folder one directory higher than the html, accessing it through subdomain.

Everything is working except the fonts. The fonts are stored in the same webroot as the stylesheet, except one folder down, in `fonts`

Should I be sourcing them with an absolute URL or is there something wrong with my css?

**EDIT:** I have a background image that is using `url()` in css working the same way, and it functions just fine.

```
body {
  background: url('img/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  font-family: typewriter;
}

/* -- FONT DEFINITIONS -- */
@font-face {
  font-family: code;
  src: url('font/code.ttf') format('truetype');
}

l33tContainer .font1 {
  font-family: code;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: typewriter;
  src: url('font/typewriter.ttf') format('truetype');
}

l33tContainer .font2 {
  font-family: typewriter;
}
/* END FONT DEFINITIONS */
```

Comment: The most likely problem is your `l33tContainer` selector -- did you create a [**custom element**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) with this name, or did you mean to use an ID or class selector? Could you please add your relevant HTML to confirm the selector, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Whoops, let me add in that `font-family: typewriter;` is defined in the body of `index.php`, `l33tContainer` is a custom element.

Comment: Awesome; what does the HTML look like? Unless you have `<l33tContainer><div class="font1">Text</div></l33tContainer>` your selector is targeting the wrong element.

Comment: Yes, I am assigning the font to elements with the classes font1,font2..etc... inside of l33tContainer, but I assign the fonts to the index with body, and it is not working there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that helped me.

Adding this to your `.htaccess` subdomain directory that is holding your fonts fixes this issue.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

[Original StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892691/font-face-fonts-only-work-on-their-own-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: typewriter;
src: url('../font/typewriter.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and make sure "l33tContainer" has class(.), or id(#)
it must be .l33tContainer or #l33tContainer

Comment: this does not work. it should work just fine the way I have it I would assume. this exact code worked fine when it was stored in the same directory as the files that call it. is the url sourcing for the fonts in relation to the css file or the file referencing it? I have a background image that references the same way, and it is working. this is just the fonts